# DS.hasMany causes a 'typekey' error when using Ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I use 'hasMany' in a model referencing ember data (canary) stored in a fixture then I get this error...

```
Error while processing route: bookings Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined
```

The other examples I've seen on SO don't seem to be the exact same problem. I've tried to recreate the problem here, if you uncomment the 'hasMany' part in this example then it errors

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yukahoduco/1/

```
App.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string')
  messages: DS.hasMany('message')
});

App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.attr('string'),
    subject: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Todo.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    body: 'First Todo',
    messages: [{
      user: 'Harry',
      subject: 'Buy shaving cream'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    body: 'Second Todo',
    messages: [{
      user: 'Bob',
      subject: 'Buy razors'
    }]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: I tried this in your fiddle and it returned an error. I don't know if a breaking change occurred in newer versions or if its a bad combination of versions. However, I can tell you this code was tested locally with `1.7.0` and `1.0.0-beta.10` (the defaults for ember-cli 0.1.2)

**Fixtures for a model:**

Fixtures, for a FixtureAdapter, are not data coming into your application, its data that is already there. So, you are creating data at the class level (not model instance) i.e. you add records as if you were saving rows to a table.

```
App.Todo.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    body: "First Todo",
    messages: [100]
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    body: "Second Todo",
    messages: [200]
  }
];

App.Message.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 100,
    "user": "Harry",
    "subject": "Buy shaving cream",
    todo: 1
  },
  {
    id: 200,
    "user": "Bob",
    "subject": "Buy razors",
    todo: 2
  }
];

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    new: function() {
      var newRecord = this.store
                          .createRecord('todo', {
                             body: this.get('newBody'),
                             messages: [100]
                          });
    }
  }
}
```

);

Then, in your model you setup your relationship like this:

```
App.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  body:     DS.attr('string'),
  // We need to set async: true for the FixtureAdapter to load the relations
  messages: DS.hasMany('message', { async: true })
});

var Message = DS.Model.extend({
  user:    DS.attr('string'),
  subject: DS.attr('string'),
  todo:    DS.belongsTo('todo')
});
```

**When not setting a fixture for a model:**

If you want to load your data with the format that is shown in the question:

```
{
  id: 1, 
  body: 'First Todo',
  messages: [{
    user: 'Harry',
    subject: 'Buy shaving cream'
  }]
}
```

You need to setup a serializer (`DS.RESTSerializer` or `DS.JSONSerializer` or `DS.ActiveModelSerializer`) that handles embedded data by passing to it a `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` during creation. See: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html

Comment: I got those versions from the CLI however the problem still persists. The minute I add a DS.hasMany then I get a 'type key' error.

Comment: Something must be wrong, a typo or name error, I tested that code and it works. I added the rest of the code where there could be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following line is causing your issues:

```
user: DS.belongsTo('string')
```

There is no `String` model declared, so this is going to result in the error you posted when the container tries to look it up. The reason it's happening when you include the `hasMany` relationship on the `Todo` model is (I think) because that forces the `Message` model to be loaded, which causes the relationships to be loaded. Without the `hasMany` relationship, the `Message` model is never used and the error is never discovered.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, that is fixed now but the error still persists